# not able to close other opened tab in browser

Tags: javascript, html

hi please check the below code i am trying to open tab  with name 
and after that  try to close that tab but unable to close 
or else can anyone tell how we can close opened all tab (url1,url2)  from parent tab (url) while close parent tab
  error in firebug is my_window is undefined

```
 <form name="submitForm1"   target="my_window"  method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/ADDMIBREP/">
            <input type="hidden" name="uname" value="uname">
            <a HREF="javascript:document.submitForm1.submit();">ADDMIBREPORT</a>
        </form>
        <a HREF="javascript: closepopup() ">remove</a>
    </body>
    <script> 

        function closepopup()
        {
            alert("hi");

            if(false == my_window.closed)
            {
                my_window.close ();
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Window already closed!');
            }
        } <script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a HREF="javascript:window.close()">remove</a>
```

OR

```
var my_first_window = window.open('test/test.html');
var my_second_window = window.open('test/test1.html');

window.onunload = function() {
    if(!my_first_window.closed)
        my_first_window.close();
    if(!my_second_window.closed)
        my_second_window.close();
}
```

Comment: <a HREF="javascript:window.close()">remove</a> it will close current window i want to close other window my_window

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of what your trying to do... http://jsfiddle.net/KjBj3/7/

```
var win = window.open("", "win","width=200,height=100");
win.document.write('<a href="#" id="close" onclick="window.close();">This is myWindow! Click to close</a>');
win.focus();
win.opener.document.write('<p>This is the source window!</p>');
```